# Why isn't a implicit optional required in a class's init method?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, option-type

I'm following a tutorial from Ray Wenderlich's website about ARC in Swift and I'm curious to know why is a optional allowed but not an implicit optional when creating a class in a playground?

The playground code I have so far is:

```
class User {
    var name: String
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
        print("User \(name) is initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        print("User \(name) is being deallocated")
    }
}

class Phone {
    let model: String
    var owner: User?
    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        print("Phone \(model) is initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        print("Phone \(model) is being deallocated")
    }
}

do {
    let user1 = User(name: "John")
}
let user2 = User.init(name: "Berry")
```

In the Phone class, if I change the owner variable to an implicit optional with an exclamation point then the playground doesn't throw an error however if I remove the question mark or don't make it optional then I receive an error.

Doesn't an implicit optional force an app to crash if it isn't set?

Any help is appreciated to get a firm understanding of why an implicit optional is okay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An implicit optional is still an optional, so it can be `nil` and it does not need to be set at the time of initialisation.  You will, however, get still get an exception **if you access it unconditionally when it is nil**.

If your `Phone` class were:

```
class Phone {
    let model: String
    var owner: User!
    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        print("Phone \(model) is initialized")
    }
    deinit {
        print("Phone \(model) is being deallocated")
    }
}
```

and you said

```
var aPhone = Phone(model:"iPhone7")
let ownerName = aPhone.owner.name
```

Then you would get an exception on the second line because the implicitly unwrapped optional is `nil`.  That line is the equivalent of writing `let ownerName = aPhone.owner!.name` if `owner` were of type `User?`.

Implicitly unwrapped optionals are very useful where a value cannot be assigned at initialisation, but a value will be assigned shortly thereafter, as it avoids the need to continually unwrap the variable.

For example, implicitly unwrapped optionals are often used for `@IBOutlet` properties in a view controller.  The property will be set by the storyboard load process, but after the view controller object is initialised.  Since you know that the property will have a value by the time any of your code runs, the use of an implicitly unwrapped optional is safe and you avoid having to continually unwrap the property.

Your sample `Phone` class is not a good use of implicitly unwrapped optionals; either a simple optional (as you have shown) or a required initialiser argument is appropriate depending on whether phones can be unowned or not.

Comment: In your example `let owner = aPhone.owner` shouldn't result in an exception.  It should result in owner having type `String?` and a nil value.  Dereferencing owner will then result in an exception.  Changing the last line to `let owner = aPhone.owner.name` will result in an exception.

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed that.